# Adding and removing events to a node

Tags: javascript

I have a js file which contains some event listeners. I want to dynamically load and unload this file.
What I thought was to create an element say `file1` and inside the file I will have event listeners like `file1.addEventListener(..)`. When I want to unload this file I will simply do `document.removeChild(file1)`. The problem is at which node should I create the events?

Edit: More details

file1

```
document.addEventListener('abc',function () {alert("abc")});
document.addEventListener('xyz',function () {alert("xyz")});
```

The above is very simple example of the file I am referring to. The events `abc` and `xyz` are generated at some other place on document node but I have control over which node these events should be generated.

Now I have say two buttons `load file1` and `unload file1`. When file1 is loaded, if event `abc` or `xyz` occurs I will see the corresponding actions. When file1 is unloaded these actions will not occur.

Comment: Can you give more details about your problem and give a sample of your code

Comment: why not just bind and unbind the events instead of loading/unloading a file? reduce the number of http requests.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to "unload" the file?

Comment: @FelixKling All the event listeners are bound to a single node. If I delete the node that will remove the listeners.

Comment: Ah ok... I still don't understand what your question is though.

Comment: @DeckerWBrower Thats the requirement. I will have such a file.

Comment: @FelixKling I am working on phonegap. I have created plugins for generating javascript events from actual phone events. Right now I dispatch them at document. Now my requirement specifies to have a file which listens on some of these events and perform some actions.  My problem is I should be able to dynamically load and unload this file. Unloading basically boils down to removing event listeners.

Comment: Ok. You can remove event handlers with `element.removeEventListener`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.removeEventListener. You just have to pass a reference to the function you want to remove, so you should probably not pass an anonymous function to `addEventListener`.

Comment: @FelixKling Then I will have to know what event  handlers I added in the file which is not known.

Comment: I don't know anything about phonegap, but wouldn't it be better then if each file kind of provides an object with a well-designed API which provides a `setup` and `teardown` method or something like this?

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah you are right. I am somehow trying to automate the teardown part given the constraint that file will attach events to a single node.